# KendoUI redirect

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create redirect in my app - if user has saved cookie than he no longer needs to see login form. I'm using different files for different views. So far I'm using:

```
window.location.href ='';
```

but that's not working when I want to add something to second screen. For example:

```
$('#test').text('test');
```

than div with id test is not found ( because it searches for it in current page ).

I know that one solution is to put everything in one page but I don't like that - it's just not clear. Maybe there is some build-in redirect in KendoUI which I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
_kendoApp.navigate(location);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `kendo.Router`
example:

`router.navigate("/items/books/59?user=John");`

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/router